# Cannot dim backlight on Packard Bell EasyNote notebook

Tags: laptop, display, backlight

My [Packard Bell EasyNote TS11HR](http://il.packardbell.com/pb/en/IL/content/model/LX.BTA02.011) notebook does not have an option for dimming the display backlight. At night, my eyes begin to hurt because of the strong light from the screen.

My laptop is 2-3 months old and I am sure it has worked before.

When I click on the battery icon in the notification area, it says in my language (Danish): 
"the setting for light does possibly reduce the life of the battery". However, I cannot dim the backlight.

I have tried downloading programs for dimming the screen but they only make the screen darker, instead of dimming the backlight. I have tried updating my drivers and looking in the BIOS for a setting. I also plan to use an Ubuntu LiveCD to try controlling it. As of now though, the backlight is locked at maximum.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Some drivers on Linux might not support the hardware of your notebook or PC.

Try to update the drivers in your Linux.

Comment: My current OS is Windows 7 but i have planned to try linux LiveCD if it can adjust my backlight

Comment: Now i have tried to use a ubuntu LiveCD to dim my screen and it didn't work. The popup says that i have turned my light down but nothing is happening.